# jquery uploadify plugin: onAllComplete fired even when there is an error

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the jquery uploadify plugin to let users upload profile pictures. I'm using ASP.NET MVC. I had a few issues that I was hoping to get help with:

```
$popup.find('#fileInput').uploadify({
    'uploader': root + '/Content/Flash/uploadify.swf',
    'script': root + '/Profile/ChangeAvatar',
    'scriptData': { 'userName': $popup.find('#UserName').val(), 'token': $popup.find('#Auth').val() },
    'cancelImg': root + '/Content/Images/cancel.png',
    'auto': true,
    'multi': true,
    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
    'queueSizeLimit': 90,
    'sizeLimit': 4000000,
    'buttonText': 'Change Avatar',
    'width': 150,
    'folder': root + '/uploads',
    'onAllComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
        //if (data.filesUploaded == "1") {
        ShowMessage("Avatar uploaded successfully.");
        //}
    },
    'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
        var msg;
        if (errorObj.type === "File Size")
            msg = 'File size cannot exceed 4MB';
        else
            msg = "An error occured while attempting to upload your avatar."

        ShowMessage(msg);
        this.hide();
    }
```

1.The onAllComplete event fires even when there is an error.  What can I check to see if there was an error?  Because if there was an error I don't want to display my success message.

2.After uploading a file, if I try to upload another file immediately after, I get an error "file is being used by another process".  I know the problem probably comes because the same file name (the username) is used even for the second upload.  But I'm not sure how I can solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is being caused by the fact that onAllComplete is not analogous to something like onAllSuccess (does not actually exist). Just like in a jQuery AJAX call, onComplete fires when the javascript is done running, with total disregard to whether or not any errors occurred. However, onAllComplete does contain the data parameter, which has the attribute "errors" which is a count of the number of errors that occured in the upload process. By checking that value, you can determine if it was a clean upload or if something went wrong.

As for the second error, I'm really not sure what can be done about that. I've encountered the same problem before and don't remember if I managed to get it fixed. The only suggestion I can give to try is to take a look at the actual php or cs or whatever the file is that you are using to actually *save* after your upload and make sure it is hanging up the file-stream and releasing its usage of the file.